# Simple indication that file is uploading after pressing Submit

Tags: html, submit

I'm looking for a simple way to show that a file is being uploaded after the Submit button is pressed.  The files can be up to 50 MB in size and users can think the browser has frozen because it takes a long time.  I'm not looking for anything animated, just something like the word Loading... that appears next to (or in place of) the submit button. An onclick might do it but I'm not sure if it would interfere with the submit process.

Answer (score 0):

Display a "spinning gif" right next to the submit button which is made visible on the onSubmit event. Redirect your form to a new page or reload current page when form is done uploading.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<script>
    $(".spinner").hide();

    function loadSpinner() {
         $(".spinner").show();

         //do validations             

         //redirect
    }

</script>
```

The form could look something like this:

```
< form onsubmit="loadSpinner()">
    .
    .
    .
    <div>
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" /> 
        <span class="spinner"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></span>
    </div>

</form>
```

This example assumes you're using jQuery.